# Unable to display data on Cortana canvas

Tags: c#, uwp, cortana

I am developing an UWP app in which i want to display some data in canvas. But I'm facing a lot of issues in  it and now i can't find out what the problem is in it.
I made a VCD file,added the command in it,edited the OnActivated function,made the Windows Runtime Component for Background task,and also made the declaration in Package.appxmanifest file, but it is not working.
Here is the VoiceCommandDefinition.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
  <VoiceCommands xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/voicecommands/1.2">
       <CommandSet xml:lang="en-us" Name="NormalCommands">
         <CommandPrefix>in app</CommandPrefix>
         <Example>Show data in canvas</Example>

            <Command Name="CanvasView">
            <Example>test cortana</Example>
            <ListenFor RequireAppName="ExplicitlySpecified"> {builtin:Cortinnum}test cortana</ListenFor>
              <Feedback>Okay Boss</Feedback>
            <VoiceCommandService Target="CanvasViewService"/>
             </Command>
                </CommandSet>
           </VoiceCommands>
```

Here is the OnActivated function from App.xaml.cs code:

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
    {

        if (args.Kind ==                    Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivationKind.VoiceCommand)
        {
            var CommandArgs = args as Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.VoiceCommandActivatedEventArgs;
            var result = CommandArgs.Result;
            var CommandName = result.RulePath[0];
            var text = result.Text;
        }
        else
            base.OnActivated(args);
    }
```

Here is the Background Service component's code:

```
using System;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.AppService;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Background;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.VoiceCommands;

namespace BackgroundService  
{
   public sealed class service:IBackgroundTask
   {
      VoiceCommandServiceConnection voiceServiceConnection;

      BackgroundTaskDeferral serviceDeferral;

    public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        serviceDeferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
        taskInstance.Canceled += OnTaskCanceled;

        var triggerDetails = taskInstance.TriggerDetails as AppServiceTriggerDetails;

        if (triggerDetails != null && triggerDetails.Name == "CanvasView")
        {
            try
            {
                voiceServiceConnection =
                    VoiceCommandServiceConnection.FromAppServiceTriggerDetails(
                        triggerDetails);

                voiceServiceConnection.VoiceCommandCompleted += OnVoiceCommandCompleted;

                VoiceCommand voiceCommand = await voiceServiceConnection.GetVoiceCommandAsync();

                // perform the appropriate command.
                switch (voiceCommand.CommandName)
                {
                    case "CanvasView":
                        VoiceCommandUserMessage userMessage = new VoiceCommandUserMessage();
                        userMessage.DisplayMessage = "Test Data";
                        userMessage.SpokenMessage = "Test data view successful";
                        var response = VoiceCommandResponse.CreateResponse(userMessage);
                        await voiceServiceConnection.ReportSuccessAsync(response);
                   break;

                    default:
                        VoiceCommandUserMessage userMessage1 = new VoiceCommandUserMessage();
                        userMessage1.DisplayMessage = "Nothing";
                        userMessage1.SpokenMessage = "NO data to show";
                        var response1 = VoiceCommandResponse.CreateResponse(userMessage1);
                        await voiceServiceConnection.ReportSuccessAsync(response1);
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Handling Voice Command failed " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    private void OnVoiceCommandCompleted(VoiceCommandServiceConnection sender, VoiceCommandCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (this.serviceDeferral != null)
        {    
            this.serviceDeferral.Complete();
        }
    }

    private void OnTaskCanceled(IBackgroundTaskInstance sender, BackgroundTaskCancellationReason reason)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Task cancelled, clean up");
        if (this.serviceDeferral != null)
        {
            //Complete the service deferral
            this.serviceDeferral.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Edit:
Here is the code of Extensions tag from Package.appxmanifest:

```
<Extensions>
    <uap:Extension Category="windows.appService" EntryPoint="Cortinnum.backgroundService.service">
      <uap:AppService Name="service" />
    </uap:Extension>
  </Extensions>
```

Comment: Since you are using `VoiceCommandService`, there is no need to post the code in your `OnActivated`, your app will not be activated as responding to this voice command, but can you please post the declaration in your manifest? Did you check your service name and command name and trigger name, are they matched? I doubt if your app service ever got started, did you debug your app service?

Comment: Have you installed the VCD file using VoiceCommandDefinitionManager.InstallCommandDefinitionsFromStorageFileAsync() when your application starts ? You can check if the registration has succeeded by opening the Cortana help and scrolling to the end of the help.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT I added the code from the Package.appxmanifest file. Is it correct ?

Comment: Sorry for the late responding, I think you used wrong service name, in manifest you named your service as "service", then `<VoiceCommandService Target="CanvasViewService"/>`, you targeted a service named `CanvasViewService`, what is this? Maybe you can try to modify the target to `service`.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT  I changed the value of target attribute to "service", but still not working. Can it be a bug in the OS ?. i have the build version 10240, which is very old one.